# Delphi IDE does not show Android devices as build targets

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi 11.1 / 11.2 within a VirtualBox (Host OS: Ubuntu). OS within the VirtualBox is Win11. My Problem: None of the USB attached Android devices are shown as build targets in the IDE project pane. On Windows 10 / Delphi 10.4 (also within VirtualBox) this worked perfectly.

I have tried the following:

- Activated USB debugging on all devices
- VirtualBox USB device settings forward all devices to the VM, Windows explorer allows browsing all the device file systems correctly
- Samsung USB driver is installed
- Google USB Driver from Android SDK is installed
- *adb devices* lists all my devices from within the VM correctly
- Running Delphi IDE from an elevated cmdln has no effect

I have a Samsung phone, Asus tablet and a CipherLab Android scanner device.
I have 3 commercial apps, and I am on a dead end now. There is very little (mostly outdated) content on that topic on Embt sites. All the guides point you to one of the above bullet points, but didn't help me.

As I'm working on X-platform projects, I post this on the Firemokey category. One could say it's more an IDE thing.

[EDIT1]: Using the context menu "Refresh" has no effect
[EDIT2]: adb devices lists all Android devices while Delphi IDE doesn't, added screenshot

[image]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "*`adb devices` lists all my devices from within the VM correctly*" - then the IDE should be listed them as well, since it gets its info from ADB. Unless this is a regression bug in the latest IDE, in which case it should be reported to Embarcadero.

Comment: You probably have but have you tried right click on Target and Refresh ?